# How to fix a twin shelving system into wall?

Tags: shelving

I need to fix this type of thing into a wall:

[image]

There are several things that I am trying to figure out which is proving elusive and thus I am here on this forum.

1. What is the proper name of this system? I have not been able to find the universal name for this shelving system so far. I have found "shelf support" and "twin slot shelving" but not a single term that is used everywhere.
2. How do I know what size screws to use when fixing these to wall?
3. Related with screw size is the size of the drill machine bit and the screw anchor. How do I find these out?
4. I went to a shop where I found two sizes, 1m and 2m. I need 1.5m. Do I cut the long one to get 1.5m? I assume so.
5. A poster in the shop said, 50kg. Is this weight limit for a single shelf or the combined shelving system?
6. How do I know how far apart to mount the two bars on the wall?
7. How do I ensure that when I mount these, they are parallel and also completely vertical?
8. There are two type of brackets to support shelf. One type has screws while the other does not have them. Is there a specific shelf type that is sold for this shelving system?

EDIT:
This is not going on drywall. The wall is made up of bricks and mortar with the plaster on it.

Comment: Need to know the type of wall first.  Is it the common drywall, plaster or cement block?  Anchors in drywall not a good idea for heavy or expensive objects, find the studs and screw into studs, about number 12, 2 inch screws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- no name (just wall shelf)

2- screw size that fits true the hole on the iron frame, length based on plugs

3- Drill size based on wall plugs

You will need a Hammer drill and special drill bits for bricks

[image: wall plugs]

4- yes cut it

5- for the shelf

6- the distance between two supports depends on the shelf sturdiness, to far and they will bend in the middle over time (suggest no more than 1 m)

7- use Leveler (it has a air bubble inside)

[image: leveler]

8- do not know, but would say with screws is better.

Comment: What type of saw is required to cut metal like this? Do I need to sand the end after I have cut it to make it smaller? If so, is it ok to just use normal sand paper for the sanding or I need to use a dremal tool?

Comment: You'll need a hack saw with at least a 32 teeth per inch blade. Sand paper will probably just tear apart due to the sharp corners.  A Dremel  tool with a fine abrasive wheel would be great. You could use a cutoff wheel to cut the pieces and forget about the hack saw.

Comment: Put the cut ends on the bottom, where you'll never see or touch them.

Answer (score 2):

There's no universal name for this. Try Googling "wall shelving units".  You'll find a whole lot of them. Once you find the one you like, then you can determine the specifics which vary greatly depending on the unit. The installation instructions will specify the type of screws for block or drywall and the length and will probably provide them, also the distance between supports. You'll need a level and possibly a drill for installation.